# $_FILES cannot access <input type="file"> in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, web, upload

Please forgive if this is a silly question.
I am trying to learn to upload an image to a website.
The code I am using is:

```
<?php

$name = $_FILES ['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES ['file']['size'];
$type = $_FILES ['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES ['file']['error'];

echo $name . $type . $size;

?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/file-data">

    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
```

And I'm getting the following error:

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\Learning\test.php on line ...

I've already checked to see if file upload is enabled in php.ini, and it is.
I already tried to nest everything inside two "if" statement, as follows:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])){
....
variables here
....
echo $name . $size . $type;
}
}
```

But in this case nothing happens in the page, even when I do select an image from the browse button.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get with var_dump($_FILES); ?

Comment: Same error +array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: it only gives me no error if I enclose it within if statement now (after changing file-data to form-data. Otherwise, it gives error says 'file' is 'undefined index'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `enctype="multipart/file-data"` to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: no problem. Next time make sure you double-check all typos before you post... :)